# Old time radio show intro/outro

Tags: terminology

I'm looking for a word that describes the intro/outro pieces tacked onto old time serial radio shows.

Specifically, the intro bit that explains what happened in the previous episode, and the outro bit that explains what to tune in for next time.

I'm guessing there must be some jargon-y in-the-industry term for such things. Any ideas?

Comment: A generic term would be a "synopsis".  The outro could also be called a "preview".

Comment: See also Tv Tropes "teaser" http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheTeaser  I'm not sure when this began in radio (certainly by the 1940s); the intro was often followed by a commercial.

Comment: @Xanne I don't think the summary of previous episodes is considered part of the teaser. The teaser is a short pre-credits scene that's part of the new episode.

Comment: But the teaser sets up the episode, they say.  So the recap is part of the set-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in television serials, the intro portion is commonly called the **recap sequence** or just **recap**. Although I'm unsure if this term was used in the industry at the time of old radio serials, it would be appropriate enough that people would understand the meaning.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recap_sequence

This refers to the sequences that often begin with "Previously, on..."

The outro promoting what to tune in for next time would be commonly called a **teaser** or **preview**, though neither term is exclusive to outro sequences.  [TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OnTheNext) just calls it "On the Next," although that's not the kind of technical term you're looking for.